# ROR + Trying to compare string with array of string

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby, string-comparison

For example:

```
array = ['text_first', 'text_second', 'text_third']
```

Now trying to compare with **'text_first_file', 'text_first_2023' or 'text11_first'**

Trying to use regex - but failing.

UseCase:

```
array includes 'text_first_file' => TRUE
array includes 'text_first_2023' => TRUE
array includes 'text_first-2023' => TRUE
array includes 'text11_first'    => FALSE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the regular expression

```
array = %w[text_first text_second text_third]
string = 'text_first_file'
p array.map { |x| string.include? x }.any?
```

Output

```
true
```